# Is there a way to use a Spring managed bean and customize it to my usecase

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

I have a use case as described below.

I am defining a webclient.builder like below.

```
@Bean(“customBuilder)
public Webclient.Builder customBuilder(Webclient.Builder builder) {
   return builder.headers().filters();

}
```

And when I try to run this, I am getting circular reference error because instead of getting spring managed builder, the above method is trying to get the same bean circularly as a first parameter. And I know, spring wont create a bean of its own if I create one myself. But the bean must be created for me here because I am using micrometer and only then it can populate traceparent in the header. I cannot use Webclient.builder() for the same reason. I cannot return Webclient either because this library will be provided as jar and other applications will customise this builder like adding baseurl, default headers, filters and build their webclient on thier own.

So, my ask is

1. Is it possible to tell spring to create a builder and return it in the above method instead of circular referencing it.
2. Worst case - populate traceparent myself without depending on internal methods. I can use tracer class here but I am not convinced to use it yet.

Comment: There are no dynamic states involved in my use case. And at the time of building the webclient, the applications using my jar are going to add dynamic states and build the webclient. I am aware of the problems of stateful singleton and here I couldn’t see any problems. Can you point me in the direction if you foresee any issues

Comment: That is why Spring Boot has the `WebClientCustomizer` which you can add so you can configure the default builder with additional extensions/configuration. That is also what other extensions use (like for loadbalancing, metrics etc. etc.).

Comment: To make an application-wide, additive customization to all WebClient.Builder instances, you can declare WebClientCustomizer beans and change the WebClient.Builder locally at the point of injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an

```
application-wide
```

additive customization to all

```
WebClient.Builder
```

instances, you can declare WebClientCustomizer beans and change the WebClient.Builder locally at the point of injection.

Finally, you can fall back to the original API and use   `WebClient.create()`

. In that case, no auto-configuration or

```
WebClient.create()
```

is applied.

Comment: I didn’t know about the webclient customizer. Exactly fits my use case. Thank you Amer and Deinum

Comment: @BalaJi It's a common design in spring to provide such customizers for all sorts of builders of beans with a more complex configuration.